# Viewing I/O Redirection in C++

Tags: c++, io-redirection

I just had a quick question.  Its been a long time since I've used redirection to feed a program large amounts of data (I'm currently using redirection to feed a few hundred thousand numbers into a program that deals with data structures).  When I run the program, I can't see the numbers being input at all.  I have a cin >> statement, but I can't see the numbers being entered.  Is this typical for redirection?  Obviously I'm not typing it in from the keyboard, but I can't recall if we should or shouldn't see it displayed on the screen.

Comment: You're not supposed to see the input.

Comment: Yes, that's entirely normal.  When you type at a terminal, the data from the keyboard is echoed back to the output — it's actually quite complex when you think about it (the keyboard and the screen are not closely associated with each other electrically, for example).  When the data comes from a file (or down a pipe), the terminal driver isn't involved so there's nothing to send the information to the screen.